# NUnit - Mock Repository and test with dummy data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I'm trying to establish a way of unit testing my service layer (& repositories) using some dummy data. I've seen examples of this before with Generic Repositories but I'm struggling to get something working whilst using a DatabaseFactory.

When I call the GetPhrase method from repository.Object I just get null back everytime.

I'm using NUnit and Moq. Any pointers on where i'm going wrong would be appreciated, or let me know if i'm better off going down a different road 
e.g. Connecting to a local db for tests (SQL CE etc)

Here are the main components of the code:

```
public class PhraseRepository : RepositoryBase<Phrase>, IPhraseRepository
{
    public PhraseRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        : base(databaseFactory)
    {
    }

    public string GetPhrase(string phraseCode)
    {
        return this.GetMany(p => p.PhraseCode == phraseCode).First().Descript;
    }

}

public interface IPhraseRepository : IRepository<Phrase>
{
    string GetPhrase(string phraseCode);
}

public class CLPRiskPhraseService : ICLPRiskPhraseService
{
    private readonly IPhraseRepository phraseRepository;

    public string GetPhrase(string phraseCode)
    {
        return phraseRepository.GetPhrase(phraseCode);
    }
}


[Test]
public void GetPhrase()
{
    var phrases = new FakePhraseData().GetPhrases();
    phraseRepository.Setup(m => m.GetMany(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Phrase, bool>>>())).Returns(phrases);

    var result = phraseRepository.Object.GetPhrase("H300");
    // Assert
    NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsNotNull(phraseRepository.Object);
    NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual("Description0", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `phraseRepository.Object.GetPhrase("H300")` in your test will always return `null` unless you set it up to return something different.

I think you're mistakenly thinking that this call to `GetPhrase` will invoke `GetMany` like the concrete `PhraseRepository` does, but you need to remember that it's just a mock of the interface `IPhraseRepository`.  A method on a mocked object will always return the default value of the return type (in this case `string`) unless you use `Setup` to change the behavior of that method.